# Recursive Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

So I'm working on an algorithms problem and am really confused on what the correct answer should look like. I have an answer, but If anyone could give me feedback/guidance I would greatly appreciate it.

Problem :

```
Casc Merge is a recursive algorithm: Assume there     
are n sorted lists, each of size m. Recursively 
Casc Merge the first n − 1 lists and then
Merge the last list (of size m) into the sorted list A (which is of size (n-1)m).

1)Write down code for it
```

Here's what I've thought of so far. It seems like I'm on the right track hopefully, but Like I said I have no clue of knowing. I tried googling and didn't get too much help on it

```
proc Cas(A, L, c)
  if c == n then
     Merge(A, L[c-1], L[c])
  end if
  else
     Merge(A, Casc(A, L, c), Casc=(A, L, c+1))
  end else
end proc
```

Again, thank you ahead of time for any advice/feedback on the psuedocode.

Assuming merge does m + n - 1 comparisons

```
S(n) = { 1                  if c = 1   
         S(n-1) + m - 1     otherwise   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close. Though, it looks like you might have a "double booking" of merges near your base case, where `c==n`, as you're merging `L[c-1]` and `L[c]` into `A`, but in the call previous to that, you're already performing a merge of `L[c-1]` with `L[c]`.

If you were to think about the recursive algorithm in terms of the definition, you could write it out using slightly more simplified logic:

```
procedure Cascade(List A, List[] L, int c)
   // base case (1-based indexing)
   if (c == 1) then
       Merge(A, L[c], {}) // merge the empty list with L[c] into A
   else
       // use the recursive definition
       Merge(A, L[c], Cascade(A, L, c-1))  // merge L[c] with L[c-1]
   end if
end procedure
```

You'd call the procedure such as: `Cascade({}, L, n)`

You can work through it like so:

```
n = 3
L = {{1 2 3} {3 2 1} {4 5 6}}
A = {}

First call to Merge yields:
Merge(A, {4 5 6}, Cascade({}, {{1 2 3} {3 2 1} {4 5 6}}, 2))

Then:
n = 2
Merge(A, {3 2 1}, Cascade({}, {{1 2 3} {3 2 1} {4 5 6}}, 1))

Then:
n = 1 (base case)
Merge(A, {1 2 3}, {})

Trickling back up the chain (actual merge results not shown for clarity):
A = {1 2 3}
A = {1 2 3 3 2 1}
A = {1 2 3 3 2 1 4 5 6}  // merged list (the actual implementation would have sorted these...)
```

and you're done! Hope this helps you out...

EDIT: Based on discussions fleshed out in the comments, the following is an example that uses returns to pass data, rather than in-place modification.

```
procedure Cascade(List[] L, int c)
   // base case (1-based indexing)
   if (c == 1) then
       A = Merge(L[c], {}) // merge the empty list with L[c] into A
   else
       // use the recursive definition
       A = Merge(L[c], Cascade(L, c-1))  // merge L[c] with L[c-1]
   end if
   Return A // return the newly merged list
end procedure
```

Comment: Ah ok I see, thank you. Is there anyway you could help me derive a recurrence for the exact number of comparisons the algorithm uses? I'm not sure how to do that, since the comparisons are done in the merge? Any help would be awesome

Comment: The basic idea is to determine how many times `Merge` will be called, and then calculate the number of comparisons per call. I can try to help you further if you still can't come up with an answer.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty sure I know how to do it. But I need to change the algorithm first. I just found out I should be using a merge(a, b) method that returns the merged list of a and b. So I don't need 3 parameters. So would that change it to Merge(A, L[c]) and Merge(L[c], Cascade(A, L, c-1)) ? I want to double check before I go solving for an incorrect algorithm. Thanks again for all your help so far

Comment: I would suggest that A also be removed as a parameter from Cascade as well, and it also return the merged lists, but it's up to you. It's probably a better practice to assume all items are immutable, and use returns to pass your data back to the caller. `Merge(A, L[], L[])` then becomes `A = Merge(L[],L[])`.

Comment: I'm not following you 100%. I edited your answer with my current answer. Is there anyway you could display what you're explaining? How would I set  A, if it's removed in the parameter

Comment: @JakeSenior see my latest edit. Note that `=` is used to imply list copying/assignment. In most languages, simply using `=` to assign a list is only assigning a reference, and not actually performing a copy. Since it's pseudocode, I think it will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, One last question. I'm trying to derive a recurrence for the exact number of comparisons. I think I did it right, but again I just learned this and am not sure if I'm correct. Could you take a look at my OP and lemme know if I'm on the right track. Again, thank you

Comment: @JakeSenior for the worst case, each merge would perform m*(n-1) comparisons, one for each item in the list A. Since the sub lists are already sorted, that would be the most you'd have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71737/discussion-between-jake-senior-and-ryan-j).